# handle error if origin doesn't allow access

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I start a ajax post call to my php file like this:

```
$.post("URL_TO_PHP_FILE", {parameter: 1}, function(response) {    
   console.log("OK")
})
```

on php side I allow the request only from a special site:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain.de');
```

If the origin is not the allowed one, I get no response or error to handle this via javascript. I get only a error message in my console.

How can I handle an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error"?

Comment: you want to catch the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error"?

Comment: check the response data - it will be empty of CORS has blocked the response

Comment: Have you tried adding an `error` handler to your $.post call?

Comment: yes I would like to catch the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) chain a fail callback, if the response has error or something failed with that request, fail callback will fired

```
$.post("URL_TO_PHP_FILE", {parameter: 1}, function(response) {    
   console.log("OK")
}).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
   // handle your error here
})
```

Comment: I'm curious, what's the status code of the response, is it `403`